# Convergence Rate of $t$ Test Statistic (Regression)

Tags: regression, t-test, inference, convergence

Consider a simple regression model, $y=\beta^Tx+\epsilon$, say using the `cars` dataset. We get the following summary:

```r
> summary(lm(dist ~ speed, cars))

Call:
lm(formula = dist ~ speed, data = cars)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-29.069  -9.525  -2.272   9.215  43.201 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -17.5791     6.7584  -2.601   0.0123 *  
speed         3.9324     0.4155   9.464 1.49e-12 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 15.38 on 48 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6511,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6438 
F-statistic: 89.57 on 1 and 48 DF,  p-value: 1.49e-12
```

The `Estimate` is the value of $\hat\beta_j$, obtained using OLS: $\hat\beta=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$;
`Residual standard error` is $s=\sqrt{\frac{SSE}{n-p}}=\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n{(y_i-\hat{y}_i)^2}}{n-p}}$;
`Std. Error` is $s_j=s\sqrt{(X^TX)^{-1}_{jj}}$ and `t value` is $t_j=\frac{\hat\beta_j}{s_j}=\frac{\sqrt{n-p}\hat{\beta}_j}{\sqrt{SSE(X^TX)^{-1}_{jj}}}$. $\hat\beta_j$ has a normal distribution, $s^2\sim\chi^2_{n-p}$ and $t_j\sim t_{n-p}$ (central $t$ under $H_0$: $\beta_j=0$). Up to here it's a well-known collection of results.

---

Now, consider a different regression problem: $y\sim\mathcal{N}(2x+1,1)$. We generate the data and build the regression model for different sample sizes:

```r
n <- 10*(1:1000)
for(i in n){
  set.seed(i)
  x <- rnorm(i)
  set.seed(i+1)
  y <- rnorm(i, 1+2*x)
  dat <- data.frame(x,y)
  lr <- lm(y~., dat)
  ct <- summary(lr)$coef
}
```

We can see that $\hat\beta_j$ is a consistent estimator of $\beta$:
[image: beta hat vs n]

and $s_j$ decay to 0:
[image: s_j vs n]

On the other hand, $t_j$ diverge with rate $\sqrt{n}$:
[image: t_j vs n]

but $t_j/\sqrt{n}$ is a consistent estimator of *something*:
[image: t_j over sqrt(n) vs n]

My questions are the following:

1. What should be the expected value of $t_j$? naturally this should be 0 (as per centralized t distribution) but I'm doubting everything right now.
2. What can I say about the value of $t_j/\sqrt{n}$? Does it have any particular meaning?
3. What can I say about the distribution of $t_j/\sqrt{n}$? Properties of the ratio distribution provide us that if $A\sim N,B\sim\chi^2_k$ then $\frac{A}{\sqrt{B/k}}$ is t-distributed, is there anything about  $\frac{A}{\sqrt{B}}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that the t-statistics in your regression output are the test statistics for tests of the null hypotheses of the form $H_0:\beta_j=0$.  The test statistic is computed *under the null hypothesis*.  Since your generative model uses non-zero values for the coefficients (contradicting the null hypotheses for the coefficient tests) it is unsurprising that the t-statistics grow as you use more data.  This merely reflects the fact that the hypothesis tests become more powerful with more data, and they are *correctly* rejecting the false null hypothesis with greater and greater evidence.

Mathematically, what is happening is the following.  Under the stipulated null hypotheses the test statistics are:

$$t_j = \frac{\hat{\beta}_j}{\hat{\text{se}}_j} \simeq \sqrt{n} \beta_j + \text{St}(n-2),$$

where the last expression gives an asymptotic form.  As you take a higher value of $n$ your t-statistics are diverging, owing to the fact that your null hypothesis is false.  The divergence occurs at order $\sqrt{n}$ so if you divide through by that order then the resulting quantities converge to the true values of the coefficients for the corresponding tests (i.e., you have $t_0/\sqrt{n} \rightarrow \beta_0$ and $t_1/\sqrt{n} \rightarrow \beta_1$).

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you please elaborate some more re. the $\text{St}(n-2)$ term?

Comment: I have used $\text{St}$ as notation for the [Student's T distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) (here with $n-2$ degrees-of-freedom).  I would personally prefer to call it the "Gosset distribution" with appropriate denotation, but unfortunately few people would recognise that name.